# Java OutOfMemory Exception Unable to start app on pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: java, android

When I try to launch my application, on Nexus 5 (Android 6 M), everything works fine, but when i'm tryning to launch it from a Galaxy S4 (4.4) or other Kitkat devices or emulator, my app sho a white screen, then crash, or crash immediately.

Android Monitor :

```
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.iotech.discover, PID: 12397
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3024)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1586)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(Window.java:1035)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.iotech.discover.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:50)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-03 14:28:48.536 12397-12397/com.iotech.discover E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think that comes from my use of bitmap background, but since I have 4 different errors, I don't know where it comes from, and it was working previously.

EDIT : My drawables are in the drawable folder and here is my main activity :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;

    @InjectView(R.id.input_email)
    EditText _emailText;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_password)
    EditText _passwordText;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_login)
    Button _loginButton;
    @InjectView(R.id.link_signup)
    TextView _signupLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.mlogin_paris_aerian);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        if (!isInternetConnected()) {
            alertDialogNoInternet();
        }

        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });

        _signupLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the Signup activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
            }
        });
    }

    public void login() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Login");

        if (!validate()/* || !isConnected()*/) {
            onLoginFailed();
            return;
        }

        _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.login_authentication));
        progressDialog.show();

        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        // TODO : onLoginSuccess si auth ok côté serveur
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        loginAPI(context, email, password);

    public boolean isInternetConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SIGNUP) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // TODO: Implement successful signup logic here
                // By default we just finish the Activity and log them in automatically
                this.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Disable going back to the MainActivity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
        finish();
    }

    public void onLoginFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.login_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
        onLoginSuccess();
        return valid;
    }

    public void alertDialogNoInternet (){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setTitle(getString(R.string.nointernet_title));
        builder1.setMessage(getString(R.string.nointernet_message));
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Merci", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        //dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder1.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
    }

    public static void loginAPI (Context context, final String mail, final String password) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("email", mail);
            obj.put("password", password);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://46.101.218.111/api/v1/auth",obj,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        //hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //hideProgressDialog();
                        System.out.println(error);
                    }
                });
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing on the login action. You are getting issue at that poing only.

Comment: In which drawable folder did you put your images?

Comment: Avoid Big size  images

Comment: Is 74Ko is really a big size for a background jpg image ?

Comment: Yes - it doesn't matter how large is file but how large is this bitmap what are dimmensions of this picture?

Answer (score 2):

Put the drawable that causes the crash in  drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-xhdpi (choose the folder which is more appropriate to your image).

Probably your image is already high-res, but because it's placed in drawable, it's regarded as a mdpi image, and the OS scales it.

Do remember that the size of the image in KB isn't a major factor in the memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks, but that just make the background displaying properly.
The app is still long to launch, and after clicking on the button on my login activity, app is freezed on devices lower and equal than KitKat.

Comment: What is the resoluion of your image?

Comment: The image 800x1264, and placed in the drawable-xhdpi folder

Comment: All looks like this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Nanoc is right: The JPEG image must first and for all have a width and height suitable for the device. 800x1264 must be rescaled, try 400x632 which uses 4 times less memory.

Comment: I cannot use something close to the native resolution of my device (full hd) ?
If I rescale at something like 600x900, in what folder should I place it, drawable, or drawable-hdpi or an other ?

Answer (score 0):

Basing on comments you gave to the other answers - big bitmap is not the only one problem. 800x1264 sized bitmap is taking 800*1254*4 bytes ~ slightly less than 4MB - it should not be a problem it it's sigle instance only.
To ensure - just comment out this line: `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.mlogin_paris_aerian);`

Probably you'll need to get familiar with hproof viewer:
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: Thanks, but did you have any idea why it makes my app unusable on devices running Android Kitkat and lower ?

Comment: Yes - memory limit is no based on physical memory installed on device, but is granted by system and depends on device / OS version.